# XPath 1.0 expression returns NULL

Tags: html, r, xpath, html-parsing, rvest

From this website, http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/ this portion of the HTML code has what I want to extract, namely, the four cities where the firm's offices are located (Knoxville, Memphis, Nashville and Sevierville)

```
<div id="the_content">
<div class="one_fourth">
<h3>
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="KNOXVILLE" style="width: 87px; height: 26px;">
<canvas width="104" height="25" style="width: 104px; height: 25px; top: -1px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
<cufontext>KNOXVILLE</cufontext>
</cufon>
</h3>
<p>
<h6>
</div>
<div class="one_fourth">
<div class="one_fourth">
<div class="one_fourth last">
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="secondary"> </div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried several variations of these XPath searches

```
require(XML)
require(httr)
doc <- content(GET('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/'))

xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'the_content']/div//p", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class = 'one_fourth']//p", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
```

All I get are NULL.  What expression will bring back the city names, or the entire address?  I know the fourth city has   so I will revise tthe final expression.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rvest](http://github.com/hadley/rvest) to the rescue via CSS selectors (XPath wld work as well):

```
library(rvest) # for scraping
library(httr)  # only for user_agent()

pg <- html_session("http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/", 
                   user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"))

# get names
pg %>% html_nodes("h3") %>% html_text()

## [1] "KNOXVILLE"   "MEMPHIS"     "NASHVILLE"   "SEVIERVILLE"

# get locations
pg %>% html_nodes("h3~p") %>% html_text() %>% .[1:4]

## [1] "One Centre Square, Fifth Floor\n620 Market Street\nPO Box 2425\nKnoxville, TN 37901\nPhone (865) 546-4646\nFax (865) 523-6529"
## [2] "40 S Main St #2900\nMemphis, TN 38103\nPhone (901) 525-8721\nFax (901) 525-6722"                                              
## [3] "424 Church Street, Suite 2500\nPO Box 198615\nNashville, TN 37219\nPhone (615) 259-1366\nFax (615) 259-1389"                  
## [4] "248 Bruce St, Suite 2\nSevierville, TN 37862\nPhone (865) 429-1999\nFax (865) 428-1612"
```

Comment: A wrapper to a wrapper to a wrapper ;)

Comment: Indeed :-) Though this should make it much easier for folks to get data, esp with the `SelectorGadget` bookmarklet Hadley included in the vignette. It fits nicely with the whole, new "piping" fad, too.

Comment: BTW rvest imports %>% from magrittr, so you don't need dplyr

Comment: @hadley, thx. I just use those three `library` calls so much that I just kinda type them by rote now :-)

Answer (score 3):

The website is checking for a user-agent. It will send you the correct content if you give it an appropriate user-agent:

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)
myAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
doc <- getURL('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/', useragent = myAgent)
doc <- htmlParse(doc)


> xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'the_content']/div//p", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
[1] "One Centre Square, Fifth Floor\n620 Market Street\nPO Box 2425\nKnoxville, TN 37901\nPhone (865) 546-4646\nFax (865) 523-6529"
[2] "40 S Main St #2900\nMemphis, TN 38103\nPhone (901) 525-8721\nFax (901) 525-6722"                                              
[3] "424 Church Street, Suite 2500\nPO Box 198615\nNashville, TN 37219\nPhone (615) 259-1366\nFax (615) 259-1389"                  
[4] "248 Bruce St, Suite 2\nSevierville, TN 37862\nPhone (865) 429-1999\nFax (865) 428-1612"                                       
[5] ""                                                                                                                             
> xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class = 'one_fourth']//p", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
[1] "One Centre Square, Fifth Floor\n620 Market Street\nPO Box 2425\nKnoxville, TN 37901\nPhone (865) 546-4646\nFax (865) 523-6529"
[2] "40 S Main St #2900\nMemphis, TN 38103\nPhone (901) 525-8721\nFax (901) 525-6722"                                              
[3] "424 Church Street, Suite 2500\nPO Box 198615\nNashville, TN 37219\nPhone (615) 259-1366\nFax (615) 259-1389"
```

otherwise it is sending:

```
> getURL('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/')
[1] "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p>You don't have permission to access /locations/\non this server.</p>\n</body></html>\n"
```